# What is it called?

Tags: terminology

I am brainstorming for an application and I am struggling to get the terminology correct.
The application has a profile page which the user can edit and an admin page.
The users will have a there profile page made public.

How are such applications like this called, CMS? I think a CMS is bigger with no public user pages.

What is the term for:

- The public profile page.
- The privage user area.
- The admin page.

Thank you. Darrell

Comment: Are you looking for one or multiple terms? The "admin page" could be the backend you're referring to.

Comment: I would suggest this question is more suited to ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes FB.. but not quite. to bloat. funny M Patel. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go with User Management System.  A CMS is a Content Management System.  And yes, that sort of thing is held from public view as it is for modifying the contents of your site.  If you need to give your USERS the ability to change things in their profile, they are not changing the content for the site, just their information in your database.